# Search within results - Google Search

Tags: google-search

How can I "search within results" in a Google Search page?

**Example:**
I want to search something from the [Google Search result of `"more useful than" firefox OR chrome`](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22more+useful+than%22+firefox+OR+chrome). How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add additional keywords to your search. Adding keywords will always reduce the amount of results you get since it uses an AND search by default.

To prove that you can do this even when OR is used, try typing the following into Google's [advanced search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search):

- all these words: `a b`
- one or more of these words: `c` OR `d`

You will notice that it results in the following Google query: `a b c OR d`

Thus, you can conclude that the OR operator only works on single words. In other words, you can think of your query as `a b (c OR d)`.

Furthermore, if you try to include multiple words in one of the OR text boxes (e.g. let's use `d e` instead of `d`), you will get the query: `a b c OR "d e"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the bottom search box in Google result page, you'll notice that just below the textbox there is a "Search within results" links. You can click on that link to narrow your query.

Internally though, it justs appends your new query to the existing query since Google uses the AND operator by default.

Comment: I remember seeing that link, but I think Google got rid of it, since I don't see it anymore.

Comment: @Senseful: Interesting, since I am seeing it *right now*

Comment: I also don't see it..

Comment: Neither me, give screenshot